# Downloading protected m3u8 video

Tags: video, web, server, download, m3u8

Maybe this is not the right forum for this question but i'm trying to download video from this https://ucha.se/watch/1325/Zvuk link. When i use some tool it gives me always an error. I tried `JDownloader, hd-video-convertor,free-ts-convertor`. No one works. I found that the player is "flowplayer" and the video comes in `.ts` files. How to downlaod such kind a protected video?

[How it looks like in dev tools image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWCba.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Turbo Download Manager (3rd edition) to download your videos.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/turbo-download-manager-3r/pabnknalmhfecdheflmcaehlepmhjlaa/related?hl=ru

Or you can use:
Stream Recorder - download HLS as MP4
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stream-recorder-download/iogidnfllpdhagebkblkgbfijkbkjdmm

I've tested them, and they both can download your video. Maybe not so fast, but they can.

Answer (score 0):

m3u8 and .ts is used for playing video by part by part using videojs-hls, if you download this file you will get nothing except duration range of video to play, there must be one main file from which m3u8 created

Comment: How to find this file? How can i download a normal video file?